# Tagging Users similar to Slack in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I built my own version of Slack using Action Cables to do the instant messaging, but one thing I'm having trouble with is the @username tagging like they do on Slack or Facebook.

Is there a Ruby Gem or tutorial that can assist with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the term for "@username" is mentions. This gem appears to implement that feature https://github.com/pmviva/mention_system

Comment: That seems like it'll do the job, but i'm just skeptical it'll work with Rails 5. I'll try it, thanks!

Edit: I guess it's not THAT old since last update was dec 2015

Comment: @JasonLee if this solved your question, would you mind marking it as the answer. If not, let me know what you are missing.

Comment: i'm still trying to get it to work. I think I'm doing the views incorrectly. I honestly hate it when they include everything in the docs...except the views.